# Distribution of points near the roots of a polynomial with bounded degree

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Let $f$ be a real polynomial of degree no more than $k$ and let $I$ be an open interval. For $\epsilon>0$, consider the set

$$S=\{x\in I: |f(x)|<\epsilon \}.$$

Let $m(S)$ denote the Lebesgue measure (this is just the sum of lengths of intervals). I wonder if we have the following estimate:

> There exist points $x_1,\dots, x_{k+1} \in S$ (Yes, $k+1$ points, NOT $k$ points!) such that the distance between any two of them is at least $m(S)/2k$ (in other words, $\frac{m(S)}{2k}$-separated).

I can only prove this when $k=2$. But how to prove this general case? (If you have to, you can replace $2k$ by other functions of $k$). I think I can also prove the case when epsilon is close to zero.

Comment: Could you provide the proof of the case $k=2$ and the possible proof for small $\epsilon$, and explain why you think this is a reasonable conjecture ?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that this degree $k$ tied to a polynomial has very little to do with the question or the answer (apart from explaining why this set is not empty, obviously some conditions are needed, as it might happen that $S$ is empty).
Your later claim also seems bizarre, as you may always change your polynomial $f$ to be $f+C$ for any $C$ without changing the degree, hence rendering your $\epsilon$ arbitrary.

So from now on, I will assume $S$ is a set of positive Lebesgue measure $m(S)>0$.

I will change your constant to $6k$ instead of $2k$.

Assume not. Take the maximally $m(s)/6k$ separated subset of $S$.
The cardinality would be $\leq k$.
Consider the set $\bigcup_{i} (x_{i}-m(s)/6k, x_{i}+m(s)/6k)$, its length is $2m(s)/3k$.
Taking the union of those $\leq k$ open sets would yield an open cover of your set $S$ of length less or equal to $(2/3)m(s)$. But $S$ is of length $m(s)$. This gives a contradiction.

P.S. Lebesgue measure is definitely not sum of length of intervals...